# Prove $f(x) =\frac {x+1}{x^2+1}, f: f: \Bbb R →\Bbb R$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus

> Prove $f(x) =\frac {x+1}{x^2+1}, f:  f: \Bbb R →\Bbb R$ is continuous.

By definition a function $f: \Bbb R →\Bbb R$ is  continuous $\Longleftrightarrow$  $\forallε > 0$,  $\existsδ > 0$ / $|x-a| < δ$  $\Longrightarrow$  $|f(x) - f(a)| < ε.$

Now 
\begin{align}
|f(x) - f(a)| 
&= \left|\frac{x+1}{x^2+1} - \frac{a+1}{a^2+1}\right|
\\&= \left|  \frac{(a^2+1)(x+1)-(a+1)(x^2+1)}{(x^2+1)(a^2+1)} \right|
\\&= \left|\frac{a^2x+a^2+x-ax^2-a-x^2}{(x^2+1)(a^2+1)}\right|
\\&= |x-a|\left|\frac{1-ax-a-x}{(x^2+1)(a^2+1)}\right|
\end{align}

Can someone please help me how to continue

Comment: While it seems like you want to prove it using the definition of the derivative, it's worth noting that this follows from the fact that if $f,g$ are continuous functions, then $f(x)/g(x)$ is continuous whenever $g(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: No, I have not seen derivates in class, so I don't know how to use derivates

Comment: @KevinLong, I think you meant to say "limit," not "derivative."

Comment: @BarryCipra Whoops, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\left|\dfrac{a^{2}x-ax^{2}+a^{2}+x-a-x^{2}}{(x^{2}+1)(a^{2}+1)}\right|\\
&=\dfrac{|x-a||1-a-x-ax|}{(x^{2}+1)(a^{2}+1)}\\
&\leq|x-a|\left[\dfrac{1}{(x^{2}+1)(a^{2}+1)}+\dfrac{|a|}{(x^{2}+1)(a^{2}+1)}+\dfrac{|x|}{(x^{2}+1)(a^{2}+1)}+\dfrac{|ax|}{(x^{2}+1)(a^{2}+1)}\right],
\end{align*}
now we see that $|a|\leq a^{2}+1$, $|x|\leq x^{2}+1$, $|ax|\leq a^{2}x^{2}+1$, so $\dfrac{|a|}{(x^{2}+1)(a^{2}+1)}=\dfrac{|a|}{a^{2}x^{2}+x^{2}+a^{2}+1}\leq 1$, and similar that $\dfrac{|x|}{(x^{2}+1)(a^{2}+1)}\leq 1$ and that $\dfrac{|ax|}{(x^{2}+1)(a^{2}+1)}\leq 1$, so 
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{a^{2}x-ax^{2}+a^{2}+x-a-x^{2}}{(x^{2}+1)(a^{2}+1)}\right|\leq 4|x-a|<4\delta=\epsilon,
\end{align*}
by choosing $\delta=\epsilon/4$.

Comment: I fixed a mistake and that doe not let me do that, I have my final result as

Comment: Let's see if anything is mistake right now with my solution.

Comment: How do you know $|a| ≤ a^2$? If I have $a = \frac1{2}$ that is not true

Comment: I was writing that $|a|\leq a^{2}+1$, not only $a^{2}$.